# Theme Preview Image does not appear on view theme admin

Tags: magento2, theme

I just following this tutorial https://jamersan.com/lets-get-started-theming-magento-2-part-1/ , in this tutorial I learn about how to make Magento Theme, but unfortunately I unable to show **Theme Preview Image**.

[image]

When my previous Themes is having it:

[image]

theme.xml (myshop/app/design/frontend/MyCompany/default/theme.xml)

[image]

The Image
[image]

Database Table

[image: Missing preview_image field value]

I am curious why the preview image does not show on my theme info page ?

Any help about it extremely appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theme Preview image loads from `app/design/vendor/theme_directory/theme.xml` file

```
<media>
          <preview_image>media/preview.jpg</preview_image> 
</media>
```

If this media tag and path to the image is not specified theme preview image will not be loaded. You can follow this link to learn about Magento 2 Themes and Theme creation https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-overview.html

Comment: I already have that file and configured well, but unfortunately the preview is not there yet

Comment: Can you please share your code

Comment: I have updated the question above

Comment: So where you have placed your preview image

Comment: it's here myshop/app/design/frontend/MyCompany/default/media/preview.png

Comment: Check this table SELECT * FROM `theme`; see the value of preview_image for your theme. Your theme path, title and preview image are registered here. Suppose if you have made some changes after the theme is registered you have to reload your admin pages for new changes to get effect

Comment: yeah, the preview_image value is missing, hmhmh weird, I have no clue why it is empty ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93036/discussion-between-raj-mohan-r-and-yusuf-ibrahim).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix that issues by deleting "design/theme/theme_id" from `core_config_data` table, and by deleting theme record in `theme` table as well. After that, I just activated theme again and thus, there is an image preview.